# UnicodeDecodeError:'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 20 ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django

In my limited experience with Python and Django,In windows,I use Python2.7 and Django1.8,I build an app and When I writing information in Setting.py about MySQL,then I write "python manage.py makemigrations" in terminal [Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHlFY.png)occured, I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: There is a typo in your command it should be `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: I think you have inserted a non ascii character in you database settings in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer sincerely.I have solved this problem with the help of my partener.I have an error in installed MySQLdb,so I reinstall it.But I don't konw why it occured 'UnicodeDecodeError:'ascii' codec byte 0xb2 ...',while I saw this error, I thought it was a decode error,after I reinstall MySQLdb,this error does not occur again.